# W3.CSS - Smaller Select Input exactly 2 digits wide

Tags: css, w3.css

I am using `w3.css` and I have a date input like so:

```
<div class="w3-padding w3-light-grey w3-border w3-border-black w3-left-align">
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">
        Date (yyyy/mm/dd):
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow"></select>/
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow"></select>/
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow"></select>
    </span>
</div>
```

What happens is (as with all `w3.css` input fields) the first select box (the year) takes up the full width of the containing `div` and the others spill over on the right.

What I want is a neat compact unit where each select is a maximum of 4 digits wide (for the year) and 2 digits wide (for the month and day). I want this on all mobiles and desktops.

Also, in general, what do I do when I do not want a `w3.css` input taking up the full width of the containing div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading I have a solution that seems to work. Hope this helps others who need to do something similar:

```
<div class="w3-padding w3-light-grey w3-border w3-border-black w3-left-align">
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">
        Date (yyyy/mm/dd):
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow" style="display: inline-block; width: auto;"></select>/
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow" style="display: inline-block; width: auto;"></select>/
        <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-yellow" style="display: inline-block; width: auto;"></select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Basically you need to overide the display and width elements of the `w3-select`'s style:

```
style="display: inline-block; width: auto;"
```